# failed to import extension journal, failed to import extension mercurial_keyring No such file or directory

Tags: python, matlab, mercurial

I am trying to open a project file in MATLAB, which I am unable to open. I am using tortoise hg for mercurial repositories

On debugging by putting breakpoint and opening the variable `FrameworkRepo`, I find the following error:

```
*** failed to import extension journal from á: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\xa0'*** failed to import extension mercurial_keyring from á: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Can someone please let me know what is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Sounds like you are using the journal extension? https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JournalExtension